# node express postgres - why and how to connect to database using pg module?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, pg

I am super new to node express and postgres and wondering the following:

```
const pg=require('pg').native
const client=new pg.Clirnt('postgres ...')
```

1. what is const?
2. pg is used to create a client to connect to the Postgres database-correct?
3. If so

`var db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/mydb')`

would work too or would I just have created a database without connecting it?

4. Why exactly do I need to connect at all-to do what?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is constant in javascript which was introduced in ES6 specification.
2. [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) is a client for PostgreSQL.
3. [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) is using node-postgres for working with PostgreSQL database, so yes, in the nutshell, it will act like node-postgres.
4. Imagine the warehouse, that's your database, where you have different shelves, that's your tables, to take or put different items into warehouse you need workers that will do your instructions like - `INSERT someitem INTO items_shelf;`. So worker is the client like Sequelize or node-postgres. The important part, warehouse should be open, otherwise, workers couldn't access to it, so your database should be turned on.

Hope I'm explained understandable enough.

Answer (score -1):

> what is const?

TLDR; variables that can't be re-assigned. scoped the same way as `var`. Part of es6.

> pg is used to create a client to connect to the postgres database?

yes, note you need to do `npm install --save pg` as well as `npm install --save sequelize`. the save flag adds the packages to the package.json file for your convenience.

> would I just have created a database without connecting it?

That bit of code should instantiate a connector - you haven't modified the database, and you also don't really know if the connection works yet.

> why exactly do I need to connect at all?

The pg library looks to use a connection pool; this means you set it up once, and then you use it repeatedly as desired and it handles the connections for you. You connect now so you can run queries against the database later.

This snippet of code connects to a postgres instance running locally on my machine, and tests that it can connect - per the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/)

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/postgres');
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('yay');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('nooo', e);
});
```